# Calculating rotations required to

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, 3d

I have a situation similar to a question [asked on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30011741) with the following image:
[image: From: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30011741]

I have an object that rests at the tip of the green arrow (point XYZ), and I'm using the following formulas to determine it's position based on alpha and beta:

```
        x = Distance * Mathf.Cos(alpha)*Mathf.Sin(beta)
        z = Distance * Mathf.Sin(alpha)*Mathf.Sin(beta)
        y = Distance * Mathf.Cos(beta)
```

But how would I find `alpha` and `beta` given point XYZ? I also need to find  distance, but I assume that would just be the distance from the tip of XYZ to the origin.

Comment: y yields cos(beta), the ratio of z and x yields tan(alpha)

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I needed @CountIblis

Answer (score 1):

What you are using is known as "Spherical Coordinates", where what you call the "distance" is written as the radius $r$, "alpha" is the angle $\theta$, and "beta" is the angle $\phi$. We then apply the Cartesian to Spherical formulas
$$r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$$
$$\theta = \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$
$$\phi = \arccos\left(\frac{z}{r}\right)$$
(Note that the formula for $\phi$ is condensed by substituting in the definition of $r$. Also, see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html) for more info on Spherical Coordinates! Also, if you want more understanding as to how we get these formulas, check out [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SphericalCoords.aspx) site, which doesn't directly give each of these but explains how each is derived [the page assumes you know about cylindrical coordinates; if not, check that out also... the same site has a great explanation!])